# Pass C# array to Jquery Function in a Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to pass a C# array to JQuery Function as a Parameter.

My C# Code to call the function is:

```
//Create an Array from filtered DataTable Column
    var GatepassIDs = defaultView.ToTable().AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("GatePassID")).ToArray<string>(); 


  //Pass Array to JQuery function                 
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "<script type='text/javascript' >FillGatePassIDSmartBox("+GatepassIDs+");</script>", false);
```

Jquery Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function FillGatePassIDSmartBox(GatepassIDs) {        

        $('#<%=txt_gatepassID.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: GatepassIDs
    });
}
</script>
```

The Problem is it is passing System.String[] from C# call instead of passing `Array` values.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing your array as a parameter directly from C#, send you array as a variable to your JavaScript. Then you can send it as a parameter to your function:

```
  var GatepassIDs = defaultView.ToTable().AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("GatePassID")).ToArray<string>();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<script>");
  sb.Append("var yourGatePassIDArray= new Array;");
  foreach(string str in GatepassIDs)
  {
    sb.Append("yourGatePassIDArray.push('" + str + "');");
  }
 sb.Append("FillGatePassIDSmartBox(yourGatePassIDArray)");
  sb.Append("</script>");

  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", sb.ToString());
```

And then use this in your JavaScript as:

```
function FillGatePassIDSmartBox(yourGatePassIDArray) {        

        $('#<%=txt_gatepassID.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: yourGatePassIDArray
    });
```

You would have to declare your array at a global context.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package, as it makes handling JSON trivial. You could do the 
following:

```
var jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GatepassIDs);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "<script type='text/javascript' >FillGatePassIDSmartBox("+ jsonArray +");</script>", false);
```

Comment: then how will they be accessed in Jquery method?

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Jquery method FillGatePassIDSmartBox param will get the string array.

Comment: I am working on SharePoint, Hence there are some limitations. can we achieve the same without using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this.

var jarr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GatepassIDs);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "FillGatePassIDSmartBox("+ jarr +");", false);